# Powershell Select-Object -ExpandProperty returning all attributes for newly-installed applications rather than the specific attribute requested

Tags: powershell, windows-installer

I have a powershell script used for rapid installation/upgrade and configuration of a suite of applications on Server 2019. Part of the process involves retrieval of the version numbers of the applications post-install (by msiexec).

I use the following inside an iterative loop to find the version no. of each .exe or .dll needed:

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\[FolderName]\* -Filter $record -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty VersionInfo`

The versions for each exe are then displayed as shown in the image [Correct Presentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jl8u.png)

However, I have come across a glitch whereby if the Version retrieval function is run immediately after the reinstall of the applications which occurs as part of the suite upgrade, the specific request for the VersionInfo attribute only to be returned is ignored, and instead the full list of attributes for each file is displayed in turn.

[Incorrect presentation showing all attributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIi1m.png)

I have inserted the following between the installs and the version retrieval function in order to get the correct presentation but to no avail:

`$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine") + ";" + [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","User")`

Critically, normal service is immediately resumed if the PS script is simply re-launched and the version retrieval function is then called on a standalone basis. But as soon as the apps are reinstalled again and version retrieval is called within the same PS session, the issue re-presents.

Would be grateful if anybody could shed any light on what is happening and what I might do to remedy?

TIA

Comment: Sounds to me like your installation process has some uncaptured output value which is leaking out to the top-level scope and appearing in the console output. If your installation process is inside a separate function (e.g. ```Invoke-MyInstallationProcess```) use one of the following to capture the return values and prevent them bubbling up - e.g. ```$null = Invoke-MyInstallationProcess``` or ```Invoke-MyInstallationProcess | Out-Null```. If the installation logic is inline in your main script, look for any calls that might be returning values, and use the same approach to capture that.

Comment: Thank you mclayton for the reply and the suggestion, and apologies for delayed response, I must have email notifications disabled, I will check. My installation process is indeed inside a separate function and I will do as you suggest and report the outcome.

Comment: Hi @mclayton you were spot on - `$null = TRIADInstallApplications` does work in suppressing the extraneous file attributes during version retrieval post-install in same PS session. However, I have to place this at the start of my script and this causes my usual text to output to console: "x installed" "y installed", with nothing actually installed at this point because it does not have the arguments. If I preface with null when calling in the normal workflow it does not work? So essentially I need to do a 'dummy run' first, then all is fine. My inexperience shining through, thanks for the help